# Mock C# class without passing the new behavior object as a parameter

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Let's say I have a C# method which does something like:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   A a = new A();
   a.DoStuff();
}
```

Is there a way I can avoid dependency injection for testing and instead of passing an `A` instance as a parameter to somehow decide a new behavior without changing the code itself? A pseudo code of what I mean:

```
public class B   
{
   public DoStuff() { //Same signature but does something else than A }
}


[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
  SetBehavior(typeof A, typeof B);
  A a = new A();
  a.DoStuff(); //here B implementation will be called
}
```

Comment: If you have VS Enterprise edition you can [use shims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2019#get-started-with-shims) or you can find another library that does it, but "shim" is what you want to search.

Comment: @Crowcoder is Shims supported by .NET core? or only .NET FW?

Comment: I really don't know. I don't use it myself, the legacy code I work with I consider a lost cause, new code is built to be testable.

Comment: I don't think, that it's possible with moq. Having a dependency injection is good not only for testing

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add an abstraction around DoStuff(), and your `MyMethod` should avoid initializing an instance of `A`.

Something like:

```
public interface IDoer 
{
   void DoStuff();
}

public class A : IDoer
{
   void DoStuff()
   {
     // do your stuff here
   }
}
```

Now, in your MyMethod, you could either add an extra argument for the IDoer or use Dependency Injection in the class that holds the MyMethod.

So:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly IDoer _doer;
   public MyClass(IDoer doer)
   {
     _doer = doer;
   }

   public void MyMethod()
   {
     _doer.DoStuff();
   }
}
```

Now, in your Test project, you can define your B class as an alternate implementation for IDoer, and create your `MyClass` with this instance. Or, you can use `Moq` to provide any behavior you want in its place.
}